# Error in the webapp while connecting with JVM using jni4net from C#

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface, jni4net

I'm trying to access a simple java code from inside my C# webapp using jni4net, but it is throwing some errors.

Generated all proxies and dlls to access the java class.

I wrote the code for connecting with JVM inside the 'Program.cs' file.

Later on the custom **java function** ie. **display_msg()** is called from the **testfunc()** which can be called from anywhere inside the bot using **Program.testfunc()**.

I'm attaching the Program.cs file and the exception occurring. 
Also I've named my java file as Test.java and it's inside package mypack.

Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using net.sf.jni4net;
using System;
using mypack;

namespace ValidationBot
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var setup = new BridgeSetup();
            setup.Verbose = true;
            setup.AddAllJarsClassPath("./");
            Bridge.CreateJVM(setup);
            Bridge.RegisterAssembly(typeof(Test).Assembly);
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddConsole();
            }).UseStartup<Startup>();

        public static void testfunc()
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.display_msg();

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to quit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Test.java

```java
package mypack;
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     int s =10;
     System.out.println(s);
  }
  public void display_msg()
  {
     System.out.println("Hello, I'm inside a java program");
  }
}
```

Exception

```
Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.dll
The type initializer for 'net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry' threw an exception.
```

I'm a beginner to C# so please help me out with this.

Comment: Does it tell you _which_ type is failing to initialize or _which_ method is missing?

Comment: It's showing error at line - Bridge.CreateJVM(setup); so I think CreateJVM is missing.

Comment: These are the 2 inner exceptions : **MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.**

Comment: Which .NET vm are you using? Is that method still supposed to be present?

Comment: I'm using .NET core 2.1. I'm stuck in this error since so many days, not able to figure out what went wrong because I'm new to .net and c#.

Comment: It is _entirely_ possible that this method is not yet implemented in .net core 2.1 or later versions.

Comment: Thanks, will check.

Comment: I checked. Yes! .NET Core 2.1 has no implementation of CreateJVM but the same program is running fine from a console app in c# but not running from a webapp in c#. It's showing no implementation found for CreateJVM in both of them.

Comment: The functions in the inner exception you showed are the cause, not createvm.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so, but no proof to back this up!

Comment: The exceptions *are* the proof I would think.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. Can you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments we deduced that .NET core 2.1 does not support this method: (and maybe others)

> System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)