# How to use Java in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, .net

I'm building a REST API with ASP.NET, which should ideally be able to use Java code. I've already managed to create a bridge between .NET and Java by using [jni4net](https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net) in a simple console application. This is absolutely necessary due the **non-existing interoperability** of .NET and Java.

Nevertheless I can't create a bridge in my ASP.NET project by using jni4net. Apparently this is a common error due the fact that .NET core 2.1 or later versions do not support the methods shown below. I am refering to this question: "[Error in the webapp while connecting with JVM using jni4net from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866038/error-in-the-webapp-while-connecting-with-jvm-using-jni4net-from-c-sharp)".

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.

Note that I'm using **.NET core 3.1** for my ASP.NET project and **jni4net 0.8.8.0**. Anyways I'm would change my .NET version if needed. My current implementation in **Program.cs** looks like this:

```cs
using net.sf.jni4net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var setup = new BridgeSetup();
        setup.Verbose = true;
        Bridge.CreateJVM(setup); // Error is thrown here
    }
}
```

Does anybody know if there is a way to bypass this error OR how to use Java code in an ASP.NET project? I highly appreciate any help or suggestion, sheers!

Comment: Ideally yes, in the real world no.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Can you please describe why so I can follow along? Do you have any example or refer for me?

Comment: The question title was changed.  You cannot do this easily.  Look into ikvm project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API is a medium that recieves requests from client, processes those requests inside and responds back to the client.

You can probably do what you want to do by creating an API on .NET Core and consume that API in your Java project.

In the simplest way, you can create an API endpoint in your .NET project's controller and send a request to that api on your Java application using the target URL of your API endpoint.
The response from your API is going to be in JSON format.

**Please note that you can consume an API regardless of the language since the communication between your application and your API is going to be via HTTP requests and JSON responses.**

Some useful video links to start with:

- How to build a restful API in .NET Core 3.1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmvcAzHpsk8&t=11447s&ab_channel=LesJackson
- How to consume an API in Java application https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fry7waUIJiY&ab_channel=PrakashShindalkar

I also would like to clarify that HTTP is just a a protocol. You can probably achieve what you want with other communication protocols as well but this one is fairly more popular and suitable for your needs.

Comment: Following up, you can also try IKVM from nuget.

Comment: Great idea - But I need to access my java code from C#, so I will probably just turn it around and build my REST API with Spring (Java). Anyways your answer gave me the basis & helped me a lot -Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know jni4net is not compatible with .NET Core. It's for .NET Framework.

*This is absolutely necessary due the non-existing interoperability of .NET and Java.*
I don't know the circumstances but it shouldn't be a necessity. Just build a service that exposes API to C# code. Voila you have a bridge. Or you can use CORBA however it's so complex it doesn't worth at all imo.

Comment: I didn't know that there is a big difference between .NET Core and .NET, so I've already learned something new today. Could you please describe your suggestion a bit more: *Just build a service that exposes API to C# code. Voila you have a bridge.*? I would highly appreciate that, sheers!

Comment: What I was saying basically you can write a web api(application programming interface) in Java which encapsulates what you need to use in C# and make calls to that api. 2 different applications that the one written in C# only asks for something and gets the result and the one written in Java does the real job. Could you be more precise about what you need to do? So I can help you better.

Comment: You already helped me a lot with that details - I'll try your suggestion! Thank you.